# Flutter run -d chrome not fetch json url

Tags: json, flutter, flutter-web

I've create Board List function by fetching json url via flutter
First I've crated into window exe it works properly like this below

[image]

But when I want to production via chrome or android
It is not working as this below

[image]

This is my code to fetch json url what did I do wrong?

```
Future<List<Schedule>> fetchBoardList() async {
  final response = await http.get('http://192.168.10.109:8888/mcschedule/machine/');
  String logResponse = response.statusCode.toString();
  if (response.statusCode == 200){
    //print('ResponseStatusCode: $logResponse'); // Check Status Code = 200
    //print('ResponseBody: ' + response.body); // Read Data in Array
    List<dynamic> responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
    return responseJson.map((e) => new Schedule.fromJson(e)).toList();
  } else {
    throw Exception('error :(');
  }
}
```